# Pycharm 4 code autocompletion does not work in IPython

Tags: autocomplete, pycharm, jupyter-notebook

Hi I've been trying out Pycharms integrated IPython and at first the code autocompletion was working just fine, but now it stopped working.. It still works in a .py file inside the IDE but not in .ipynb files. Any idea why this would be happening?

Comment: `ipynb` files are `json` files and not meant to be edited directly. What are you actually trying to do here?

Comment: what im saying is that the code autocompletion works if you are working on a .py file as in 'some_script_of_mine_.py' but it doesnt work in .ipynb files

Comment: Yes, but IMO this is expected behavior, since you are not supposed to edit `.ipynb` files directly.

Comment: its an ipython notebook script opened in IDE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK by trial and error I got a fix. For some reason if you put %pylab inline or %matplolib inline in the same cell with your imports this will mess up the code autocompletion. Put %pylab in its own cell and it fixes the problem